# Grails mail plugin: attach org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile

Tags: spring, email, grails, attachment

I cannot figure out how to do attachments.  Installed plugin "mail" and the file in question is a .csv being uploaded (successfully) from a form.

This works:

```
def f = request.getFile('uploadedFile')
//do a bunch of stuff with f and make bodyString
MailService.sendMail {
  to "myemail@secretplace.com"
  subject "subject"
  body bodyString
}
```

This doesn't:

```
def f = request.getFile('uploadedFile')
//do a bunch of stuff with f and make bodyString
MailService.sendMail {
  multipart true
  to "myemail@secretplace.com"
  subject "subject"
  body bodyString
  attach "myfile.csv", f
}
```

Oh yeah the error says this:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: my_project.MySweetController.attach() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl, org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile) values: [Demo myfile.csv, org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile@73e2d16b]
Possible solutions: each(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using version 0.9 or later of the mail plugin, the following should work

```
def f = request.getFile('uploadedFile')

//do a bunch of stuff with f and make bodyString
MailService.sendMail {
  multipart true
  to "myemail@secretplace.com"
  subject "subject"
  body bodyString
  attachBytes "Some-File-Name.csv", "text/csv", f.bytes
}
```

incidentally, the name of your reference to the mail service `MailService` is peculiar. If you're getting a reference to this service by autowiring the Spring bean, I would expect it to be `mailService`

Comment: f.getBytes() is what I have now.  Thank you!!